# Squared shaped points change in legend - ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, point, shapes

I am plotting a few points with `ggplot` and I would like to highlight one of them with an empty-square shaped point. I do it in the following way:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(7), y=rnorm(7)), aes(x,y))+
geom_point(aes(shape = "Points"), size=1.4)+
geom_point(data = data.frame(x=rnorm(1),y=rnorm(1)), aes(shape="Square"), size = 1.9, stroke = 1.7) +
coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3,3),ylim = c(-3,3))+
scale_shape_manual(name = "Shape", values = c(16,0))
```

The square shaped point in the plot is fine, but the one in the legend is thicker than the point in the plot. More precisely, it looks thicker, but it actually has a second thin inner square, which I can see when I export the plot with tikzDevice (see following pic).

[image: Legend points difference]

The issue persists even trying to modify the shape in the legend directly in the following way:

```
guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=c(16,0))))
```

Can you help me see how to get the point in the legend to simply look like the point shape 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the stroke width in the legend; if you set it to 1 you get two perfectly overlaid squares (if you set it to NULL, 0, or NA, you get none at all, though):

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(7), y = rnorm(7)), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = "Points"), size = 1.4) +
    geom_point(
        data = data.frame(x = rnorm(1), y = rnorm(1)),
        aes(shape = "Square"),
        size = 1.9,
        stroke = 1.7
    ) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-3, 3), ylim = c(-3, 3)) +
    scale_shape_manual(name = "Shape", values = c(16, 0)) +
    guides(shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=c(1, 1.4), stroke = 1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works fine (increasing size and stroke to 1.9 and 1.7 in `override.aes`), so I guess the issue was that ggplot, when grouping the two point sets in the shape legend, increased the stroke of the 0 shaped point in the legend. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try one of the themes? +theme_economist() may fix the legend issue

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to specify that I am using theme_light(). Anyway, even trying other themes, such as the Economist's one, the problem persists.